# connecting USB wireless headset disables either mouse or keyboard (somethimes both)

Tags: usb, input-devices

When I connect my headset, it disables either my mouse, keyboard, or both.
The funny thing is, when I then disconnect the headset again, the commands (e.g. from keyboard) suddenly seem to come through after all (e.g. alt-tab).
I find this spooky. What is going on and **how can I use all 3 devices at the same time again?**

More info:
I have a steelseries arctis 7 which used to work fine with ubuntu 18.
It makes a wireless connection with a USB dongle.
I upgraded ubuntu 18->20 *and* my motherboard. Before these changes everything worked fine.
The new mobo only has 2 USB ports available, so I use extra USB ports I have on my monitor.
dmesg output after I disconnect headset contains: `retire_capture_urb: 442 callbacks suppressed`

UPDATE 1: More dmesg -w output:

#### connect headset

```
[  164.293821] usb 8-1.1.3: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  164.468197] usb 8-1.1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1038, idProduct=12ad, bcdDevice= 1.19
[  164.468199] usb 8-1.1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=5, SerialNumber=0
[  164.468200] usb 8-1.1.3: Product: SteelSeries Arctis 7
[  164.468201] usb 8-1.1.3: Manufacturer: SteelSeries 
[  164.891992] input: SteelSeries  SteelSeries Arctis 7 Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.3/8-1.1.3:1.5/0003:1038:12AD.0005/input/input22
[  164.954077] input: SteelSeries  SteelSeries Arctis 7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.3/8-1.1.3:1.5/0003:1038:12AD.0005/input/input24
[  164.954256] hid-generic 0003:1038:12AD.0005: input,hiddev1,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [SteelSeries  SteelSeries Arctis 7] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1.3/input5
### not sure what the next device is or why it's outputting a message.
[  242.213849] usb 8-1.1.1: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
### <mouse still works here>
### use headset (no message in dmesg output, but now mouse stops working)
### <no message>
### disconnect mouse (stopped working after use headset)
[  313.315054] usb 8-1.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 6
### connect mouse (still not working)
[  316.620085] usb 8-1.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  316.743763] usb 8-1.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=09da, idProduct=9090, bcdDevice= 1.91
[  316.743767] usb 8-1.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  316.743770] usb 8-1.1.4: Product: USB Device
[  316.743772] usb 8-1.1.4: Manufacturer: A4TECH
[  316.754514] input: A4TECH USB Device Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.4/8-1.1.4:1.0/0003:09DA:9090.0006/input/input25
[  316.812511] input: A4TECH USB Device System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.4/8-1.1.4:1.0/0003:09DA:9090.0006/input/input26
[  316.812643] input: A4TECH USB Device Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.4/8-1.1.4:1.0/0003:09DA:9090.0006/input/input27
[  316.812750] input: A4TECH USB Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.4/8-1.1.4:1.0/0003:09DA:9090.0006/input/input28
[  316.813064] hid-generic 0003:09DA:9090.0006: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [A4TECH USB Device] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1.4/input0
[  316.818475] input: A4TECH USB Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.4/8-1.1.4:1.1/0003:09DA:9090.0007/input/input29
[  316.818636] hid-generic 0003:09DA:9090.0007: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [A4TECH USB Device] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1.4/input1
### disconnect kb (mouse still not working)
[  411.887329] usb 8-1.1.2: USB disconnect, device number 5
### disconnect mouse, reconnect mouse (same USB)  (mouse still not working)
[  427.242672] usb 8-1.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 9
[  432.092033] usb 8-1.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[  432.215941] usb 8-1.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=09da, idProduct=9090, bcdDevice= 1.91
[  432.215945] usb 8-1.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  432.215948] usb 8-1.1.4: Product: USB Device
[  432.215953] usb 8-1.1.4: Manufacturer: A4TECH
[  432.227029] input: A4TECH USB Device Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.4/8-1.1.4:1.0/0003:09DA:9090.0008/input/input30
[  432.284586] input: A4TECH USB Device System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.4/8-1.1.4:1.0/0003:09DA:9090.0008/input/input31
[  432.284777] input: A4TECH USB Device Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.4/8-1.1.4:1.0/0003:09DA:9090.0008/input/input32
[  432.284925] input: A4TECH USB Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.4/8-1.1.4:1.0/0003:09DA:9090.0008/input/input33
[  432.285146] hid-generic 0003:09DA:9090.0008: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [A4TECH USB Device] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1.4/input0
[  432.290892] input: A4TECH USB Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.4/8-1.1.4:1.1/0003:09DA:9090.0009/input/input34
[  432.291075] hid-generic 0003:09DA:9090.0009: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [A4TECH USB Device] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1.4/input1
### disconnect mouse, reconnect mouse in kb USB port  (mouse still not working)
[  443.627740] usb 8-1.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 10
[  449.759259] usb 8-1.1.2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[  449.879118] usb 8-1.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=09da, idProduct=9090, bcdDevice= 1.91
[  449.879122] usb 8-1.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  449.879125] usb 8-1.1.2: Product: USB Device
[  449.879127] usb 8-1.1.2: Manufacturer: A4TECH
[  449.890031] input: A4TECH USB Device Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.2/8-1.1.2:1.0/0003:09DA:9090.000A/input/input35
[  449.947677] input: A4TECH USB Device System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.2/8-1.1.2:1.0/0003:09DA:9090.000A/input/input36
[  449.947798] input: A4TECH USB Device Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.2/8-1.1.2:1.0/0003:09DA:9090.000A/input/input37
[  449.947895] input: A4TECH USB Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.2/8-1.1.2:1.0/0003:09DA:9090.000A/input/input38
[  449.948075] hid-generic 0003:09DA:9090.000A: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [A4TECH USB Device] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1.2/input0
[  449.953793] input: A4TECH USB Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.2/8-1.1.2:1.1/0003:09DA:9090.000B/input/input39
[  449.953971] hid-generic 0003:09DA:9090.000B: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [A4TECH USB Device] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1.2/input1
### connect kb in mouse USB (kb does not work anymore either)
[  467.414376] usb 8-1.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[  467.543293] usb 8-1.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=2516, idProduct=0011, bcdDevice= 1.11
[  467.543299] usb 8-1.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  467.543303] usb 8-1.1.4: Product: Quickfire TKL 6keys
[  467.543306] usb 8-1.1.4: Manufacturer: CM Storm
[  467.549900] input: CM Storm Quickfire TKL 6keys as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.4/8-1.1.4:1.0/0003:2516:0011.000C/input/input40
[  467.606841] hid-generic 0003:2516:0011.000C: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CM Storm Quickfire TKL 6keys] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1.4/input0
[  467.613534] input: CM Storm Quickfire TKL 6keys System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.4/8-1.1.4:1.1/0003:2516:0011.000D/input/input41
[  467.674591] input: CM Storm Quickfire TKL 6keys Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1.1/8-1.1.4/8-1.1.4:1.1/0003:2516:0011.000D/input/input42
[  467.674748] hid-generic 0003:2516:0011.000D: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [CM Storm Quickfire TKL 6keys] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1.4/input1
### disconnect headset: both kb and mouse work again
[  488.942840] usb 8-1.1.3: USB disconnect, device number 8
```

Comment: Can you edit your post with `dmesg -w` output, running before you do your things ? Also, please add some comments on the output (ie ### I plug, keyboard don't work // ### I unplugged, keyboard work again with alttab anything)

Comment: @B.duGaray I added the output, though for some reason I noticed today that on one instance (after I recorded the dmesg output) my mouse stopped working right after I _removed_ the headset. So there might be something more difficult going on, but for sure I can trigger it using the headset. I suspect maybe the USB stuff on my motherboard are faulty...